# I need help fixing a command (node.js

Tags: node.js, discord.js

[image]

I can't get this code to work. I am trying to check if a user has this role and ban them.

Comment: What's the intended function?

Comment: this is supposed to act as a ban command but the code up above in the image is supposed to be to check if the person has this role

Comment: Please add more information about the problem.

Comment: I edited the question to make the intended function clearer, is what I wrote right? If it is right, are you checking the user you mention or all users in the server?

Comment: Its actually supposed to check the user who sent the message roles to see if they have the role "ban"

Comment: Code in questions here should be pasted into your question as TEXT, not as an image and then formatted appropriately as code here.  This is so that people on mobile devices can see it, so that people can copy portions of your code into answers without retrying it all, so it can be indexed by search engines, etc...  Please edit your question to include the code as plain text and formatted appropriately as code.  Plus, I can't even read that image.

Comment: Please update the post with a code example (not a photo) and more information about what the intended purpose is, what's not working, and what's expected to happen. "This is supposed to act as a ban command" and "check the user who sent the message roles" aren't the same thing.

Answer (score 0):

You're going about it the wrong way, you don't need to look for the `ban` role, you just need to check if the `GuildMember` has a role named `ban`

```js
if (message.member.roles.cache.some(role => role.name === 'ban')) return message.member.ban({ reason: 'Had the ban role' })
```